# A Basic Python Question about Defining Function

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a basic question regarding Python code.

For example,

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

loss = nn.MSELoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.randn(3, 5)
output = loss(input, target)
output.backward()
```

Why do I need to define the loss function at the first line? I can't replace `loss()` at the 4th line with `nn.MSELoss()`.

Comment: @PearlSu You should be able to replace this line with `output = nn.MSELoss()(input, target)`

Comment: In this code, u have defined `loss` as an object and not as a function. and then you have initialized it with `output = loss(input, target)`. Read more about __init__ method of python classes.

Comment: This isn't about Python so much as it is about a specific 3rd party module.

Comment: maybe for short?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake here. I am using PyTorch package, and I miss two lines in the front.  1. import torch   2. import torch.nn as nn

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks! Yes, you are correct. Since loss=nn.MSELoss(), I should include the bracket too. And the first bracket () refers to the parameters for the original object, the second bracket (input, target) refers to the inserted data.

Answer (score 2):

As a few others have pointed out, `nn.MSELoss` is a class and not a function. In line 1 you are creating an object of type `torch.nn.modules.loss.MSELoss`. And because it inherits from `nn.Module`, you can call this object like you would call a function, like you do in line 4.
If you don't want to use the MSELoss class, you can also `import torch.nn.functional as F` and then use `F.mse_loss(input, target)` directly (this is what pytorch normally calls for you).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, anything can happen, because when you import a module code is executed and everything in Python is dynamic.

In practice however most probably the fourth line behave if written as

```
output =  nn.MSELoss()(input, target)
```

without assigning it to a `loss` variable first.

I'm assuming that `torch.randn` doesn't depend on the fact that you already created a loss thing before. That would be technically possible but really un-pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why do I need to define the loss function at the first line?*

`nn.MSELoss` is a Class. When you write `loss = nn.MSELoss()`, you are creating an Instance Object of MSELoss Class. That´s not a function, as you said.

> *I can't replace loss() at the 4th line with nn.MSELoss()*

You are right, you need to use an object to access the attributes and methods of that class. You can´t access directly from the class.